# Spring MVC form example without JSP

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Can a Spring MVC form example work without any JSP files? I am working on a project which is using htm templates and i wish to use Spring MVC forms in it. So is it possible to include Spring MVC forms without having JSP files?

Comment: Stephen can you please help me out with an example that uses spring MVC form submission without the use of JSP files

Answer (score 0):

Spring is able to use [multiple view technologies](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/reference/view.html) beyong JSP, such as Velocity and Freemarker.  Additionally, if you use AJAX, you can just use plain HTML with JavaScript.  Since you are using HTM templates, my suggestion would be to [use jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), or some other JS framework, to submit your HTM forms.